# Distinguish Offline payment methods in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

How can I distinguish which are offline payment methods and online payment methods in Magento?

Comment: Do you want to check it programmatically? Otherwise, you need to check all the available payment methods and decide manually

Comment: Yes I want to check it Programmatically.